# select all rows if sum with condition is met

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with these fields:

```
day (date)
name (string)
description (string)
cost (float)
```

I'd like to select all rows where the sum of cost, grouped by day, where name = x, is greater than 0.

For example, if on 18 Jan the sum of cost where name = x is 15 I'd like all rows (including the ones where name != x).  If on 17 Jan the sum of cost where name = x is 0 then I don't want any rows at all.

It seemed like I could do this with a sum(cost) over(partition by) but it doesn't seem I can add where clauses in the partition.

Answer (score 0):

It was little difficult to understand without input and expected output, however, if I have understood your requirement you could use `QUALIFY` in your query as below.

This filters out the `row 3 and 4`, where `sum_of_cost` is `0`.

Hope this helps?

```
   with cte as (
  select DATE '2024-01-15' as day, 'ABC' as name, 'Text1' as description , cast(912.23 as float64) as cost
  UNION ALL
  select DATE '2023-01-15' as day, 'XYZ' as name, 'Text2' as description , cast(12.23 as float64) as cost
  UNION ALL
  select DATE '2024-01-17' as day, 'WEQ' as name, 'Text3' as description , cast(0.0 as float64) as cost
  UNION ALL
  select DATE '2024-01-17' as day, 'TTT' as name, 'Text3' as description , cast(0.0 as float64) as cost
  UNION ALL
  select DATE '2024-01-15' as day, 'RAW' as name, 'Text4' as description , cast(88.23 as float64) as cost
  UNION ALL
  select DATE '2024-01-15' as day, 'ABC' as name, 'Text5' as description , cast(1211.23 as float64) as cost
) SELECT cte.*,SUM(cost) over (partition by day order by day, name, cost ) as sum_of_cost,
FROM cte
qualify sum_of_cost > 0
```